# Matching nested [quote] in using RegExp

Tags: html, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to get regexp to match some nested tags. (Yes I know I should use a parser, but my input will be correct).

Example:

```
Text.
More text.
[quote]
First quote
[quote]
Nested second quote.
[/quote]
[/quote]
```

Let's say I want the regexp to simply change the tags to `<blockquote>`:

```
Text.
More text.
<blockquote>
First quote
<blockquote>
Nested second quote.
</blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

How would I do this, matching both opening and closing tags at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't match (arbitrarily) nested stuff with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

But you can replace every instance of `[quote]` with `<blockquote>` and `[/quote]` with `</blockquote>`.

Comment: Caveat: You can match nested stuff to a predetermined depth: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-recursion

Comment: "You can't match (arbitrarily) nested stuff with regular expressions."

That's the answer I was looking for :)

So I used a BBCode parser:
http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t mind correctness, then you could use a simple string replacement and replace each tag separately. Here’s some example using [PHP’s `str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) to replace the opening and closing tags:

```
$str = str_replace('[quote]', '<blockquote>', $str);
$str = str_replace('[/quote]', '</blockquote>', $str);
```

Or with the help of a regular expression (PHP again):

```
$str = preg_replace('~\[(/?)quote]~', '<$1blockquote>', $str);
```

Here the matches of `\[(/?)quote]` are replaced with `<$1blockquote>` where `$1` is replaced with the match of the first group of the pattern (`(/?)`, either `/` or empty).

But you should really use a parser that keeps track of the opening and closing tags. Otherwise you can have an opening or closing tag that doesn’t have a counterpart or (if you’re using further tags) that is not nested properly.

Comment: @KennyTM: Ah, thanks for the remark. I don’t know how I assumed that he wants to use PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lousy idea, but you're apparently trying to match something like: `\[\(/?\)quote\]` and replace it with: `<\1blockquote>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 expressions.

```
s/\[quote\]/\<blockquote\>/
s/\[\/quote\]/\<\/blockquote\>/
```